# Taskfile, how to run only if binary not exists?

Tags: taskfile

How to create [precondition](https://taskfile.dev/usage/) that only run if the binary not exists?

```
tasks:
  migrate:
    desc: Get golang-migrate
    cmds:
      - echo running wget bla bla
    preconditions:
      - sh: "test -z {{.MIGRATE_BIN}}"
        msg: "found, ignoring"
    vars:
      MIGRATE_BIN:
        sh: which migrate || true
```

or what kind of shell commands supported inside `sh`? it it based on `$?` return value or?

In normal shell I only need to do this:

```
MIGRATE_BIN=`which golang-migrate`
if [[ -z "$MIGRATE_BIN" ]]; then
   echo "do wget bla bla"
fi
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah should use `status` instead of `precondition`

```
tasks:
  migrate:
    desc: Get golang-migrate
    cmds:
      - echo running wget bla bla
    status:
      - test -f {{.MIGRATE_BIN}}
    vars:
      MIGRATE_BIN:
        sh: which migrate || true
```